# Saving to database, then reading from database, data is not there

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have this page, where the user can modify it's information. When the page loads, it fills in the users information into the text input fields. You can then change your information and hit save. The data should be saved to the database and that should also be reflected in the text fields, because of the refresh. But it does not save the data. If I remove the reading of the data, the data is saved when the button is clicked, but when the data reading is there, the data is not saved.

This is the code in the "read the data" part, this is in the Page_Load():

```
string loggedInUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    SqlConnection ConnectDb = new SqlConnection("Data Source=serverHere;Initial Catalog=catalogHere;User ID=userNameHere;Password=passwordHere;"); //Opretter database connection string
    SqlDataReader infoReader = null;
    SqlCommand getUserInfo = new SqlCommand("SELECT firstName,lastName,age,city,contact,bio FROM UserInfo WHERE userName = @userName", ConnectDb);
    getUserInfo.Parameters.Add("@userName", loggedInUser);
    ConnectDb.Open();
    infoReader = getUserInfo.ExecuteReader();
    infoReader.Read();
    {
        tbInfoFirstName.Text = infoReader["firstName"].ToString();
        tbInfoLastname.Text = infoReader["lastName"].ToString();
        tbInfoAge.Text = infoReader["age"].ToString();
        tbInfoCity.Text = infoReader["city"].ToString();
        tbInfoKontakt.Text = infoReader["contact"].ToString();
        tbInfoAbout.Text = infoReader["bio"].ToString();
    };
    ConnectDb.Close();
```

This is the code for the save button:

```
string loggedInUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    SqlConnection ConnectDb = new SqlConnection("Data Source=serverHere;Initial Catalog=catalogHere;User ID=userNameHere;Password=passwordHere;"); 
    SqlCommand SavePersonInfo = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserInfo SET firstName = @firstName,lastName = @lastName,age = @age,city = @city,contact = @contact,bio = @bio WHERE userName = @userName", ConnectDb);
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", tbInfoFirstName.Text); 
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", tbInfoLastname.Text);
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", tbInfoAge.Text);
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", tbInfoCity.Text);
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", tbInfoKontakt.Text);
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bio", tbInfoAbout.Text);
    SavePersonInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", loggedInUser);


    ConnectDb.Open(); 
    SavePersonInfo.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    //Response.Redirect("Manage.aspx"); 
    ConnectDb.Close();
```

As said, the save code works on it's own, but not when the reading code is also active, eg: Not commented out.

Comment: Please debug what part (selecting or inserting) is failing by looking into your database with a tool.

Comment: `Page_Load` fires before button event handlers in Webforms.

Comment: Yes, it reads the data when the page loads. But should it not just do it once?

Comment: try to put the loaded data into a !ispostback

Comment: KratosMafia, that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the Page_Load event is launched before the event button on PostBack.
In this case the reading taken are the old data again filling the fields and finally recording the old data again.
Have you checked it?

If so, put your code in Page_Load in an if (IsPostBack!):

```
public void Page_Load() {
    // ...

    if (!IsPostBack) {
        // code read the data
    }
}
```